# How do I constrain the trendline so it takes a minimum and maximum y value?

Tags: excel, range, linear-regression, trendline

I have taken data from
https://www.kaggle.com/budincsevity/szeged-weather
I have extracted just the temperature and humidity columns and I treated values where humidity=0 as outliers and removed them

I have produced a scatter plot with a trendline in Excel, however the trendline takes humidity values >1, when the measurement for humidity is constrained such that 0<=humidity<=1

Is there a way to constrain the values a trendline can take? ie. set a min and max y-value?

I have tried to constrain it by constraining the values the humidity data cells can take (between 0 and 1), but this hasn't affected the trendline.

I need this in Excel, I know Excel isn't the best program to do regression on, however I'm delivering a very basic course which includes (basic) linear regression which I need to deliver in Excel

Comment: Would you post a link to the data you extracted? The original link in your post will not allow a download unless I register.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: One way is to add some text data to the post itself, say 10 or 15 rows of data. That should be enough to help create a useful answer or example.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Adding Equation of Line]

New Note: In this graph you can note the equation of the trendline, which dictates how much y moves according to x value value. So, plot the different values of x to recreate the value of y. This way you will be able to add the trendline as a graph built by yourself.

Previous Answer:Im not too sure what you are asking but Im gonna dare to give you an answer. Excel trendlines provide the equation that builds them. Jot it down, take the trendline off the graph and rebuild the line with the equation and your limits of x and y.

Comment: How would I 're-build'?
I'm really looking for a way to just do it all in Excel

Comment: I just updated my answer to reflect a better explanation on how to do it.

Comment: So it would be like you've done, however the trendline would be restricted to only take y-values >0.5 for example, so currently the start of the trendline is out of the given range, so I'd want that bit altered.